# Although a request is being sent to the server why isnt the onload function being called?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, xmlhttprequest

Here is the body of my function:

```
alert("called")
var Ttype = ""
var Ttext = ""
if(document.getElementById('blockArea').style.backgroundColor != ''){
     Ttext = document.getElementById('linkArea').value;
     Ttype = "link";
}else{
     Ttext = document.getElementById('blockArea').value;
     Ttype = "block";
 }

if(!(Ttext == "") && !(Ttext == null)){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
console.log("send");
alert("xhttp")
xhttp.send("data=*_website_*" + "*/*/" + encodeURIComponent(Ttype) + "*/*/" + 

xhttp.onload = function () {
  
  alert("onload")
  console.log("onload");
  var response = xhttp.response;
  console.log("response");
  setGlobalResponseVals(response, Ttext);
  setupTabs();
  }
  xhttp.onerror = function () {
    console.error('Error:', xhttp.statusText);
    alert('Error: ' + xhttp.statusText);
  };

};
```

}

The on-load function is being completely ignored although my server got the post request. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Also this same code worked for my chrome extension but its not working for my website.

edit:
the error handling is printing nothing

[Left is what the server received and on the right is what the js printed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvVRK.png)

Comment: Check the Network control panel to see if you're getting a response.

Comment: Add an error handler and find out. My guess is CORS

Comment: Also, if you can help it, I'd recommend you switch to the much more modern and simpler [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). See examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples).

Comment: @epascarello I added an error handler, although it seems to be called nothing is printing and what is CORS?

Comment: What do you see in your developer console in the browser? How is this code called?

Comment: @SamitManjunath — CORS is a thing you can [use a search engine to find a guide to](https://duckduckgo.com/?va=w&t=hk&q=CORS&ia=web).

Comment: Oh wait @epascarello you were right:
i get this error
cess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I am sure there are plenty of questions/answers for CORS Flask on the site.